# Array of object have further inner array of object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My class

```
class ScoreModel {
    var playerId: Int?
    var holeScores: [HoleScore]?
}
```

Other Class

```
class HoleScore {
    var holeScore: Int?
}
```

I have these classes one is `ScoreModel` class which can have Array of objects of `HoleScore`

```
let scoreList = [ScoreModel]()
scoreList[0].holeScores![0].holeScore = 3
```

When i update or change `holeScore` for `scoreList[0].holeScores[0]` it changes it for all the `scoreList[forAllIndexes].holeScores[0]`. I just want to change the inner array prams for given index of outer array but it changes all the `holeScore` values when ever update.

Comment: Remember that class has reference semantics, how `scoreList` filled?

Comment: It looks like you appended always the same `HoleScore` instance to `holeScores`

Comment: Please check `holeScores` size

Comment: Better change to struct if you are not familiar on dealing with reference type

Comment: thank u  @Tj3n  using struct solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved my problem converting my classes to struct .I just did not know how to deal with this reference types in a nested sub arrays .So I used struct

```
   struct ScoreModel {
        var playerId: Int?
        var holeScores: [HoleScore]?
    }

   struct HoleScore {
    var holeScore: Int?
   }
```

Now setting value for a specific inner index will not effect others

```
let scoreList = [ScoreModel]()
scoreList[0].holeScores![0].holeScore = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

This appends the same object , so change in one reflects to others

```
var item = HoleScore()

for i in 0...5
{
    item. holeScore = i

    scoreList[0].holeScores.append(item)
}
```

//

This appends different objects , so change in one doesn't reflects to others

```
for i in 0...5
{
    var item = HoleScore()

    item. holeScore = i

    scoreList[0].holeScores.append(item)
}
```